# How to change value of a selection using Python on Tryton

Tags: python, tryton

Is there a way to change selection field value using Python and I didn't find any documentation to use .
The state field is a field that describe a treatment state

I wish to do something like :

```
state=fields.Selection([
        ('stopped', 'Stopped'),
        ('wait', 'Wait'),
        ('finished', 'finished'),
        ], 'State', readonly=True)

def changeselectionvalue(self,state)
    self.state=state #something to do this
```

Help me please I am a new user of a Tryton

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with? Binding an action to your method, or actually changing the value of the field?

Comment: change the value of the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the write API:

```
records = Model.search([]) #Get all the records you wan to write. 
Model.write(records, {'state': 'new_state'})
```

Or the ActiveRecord pattern:

```
self.state = 'new_state'
self.save()
```

'new state' must be one of the internal values of the selection.

The first is recomended when you have to update more than one record in a bunch.

If you're model subclasses the Workflow class, It's recommended to use the @Workflow.transition(new_state) decorator in order to change the state of the records, as it only updates the records for which the transition is valid.